# Issue in WebView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, webview, scrollview, toolbar, material-design

I placed a WebView in a NestedScrollView. To hide/show the toolbar when the user scrolls down/up in the WebView.

Unforunatly, there are issues:

1. When clicking on a URL in a webpage that navigates to a smaller webpage (in height), a blank area appears at the bottom of the webview. When I remove this
2. a javascript viewpager in the HTML has sidescrolling issues, javascript is enabled in my WebView though.

When I remove the NestedScrollView, both issues are gone, but the toolbar hiding&showing doesn't work anymore

here's my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/toolbarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="57dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/focusHolder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/tmpBtn"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="@null" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/addressBar"
                        style="@style/addressBarStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tmpBtn"
                        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/darkGreen"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/webViewWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/yellow">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- Nav drawer -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.fastbrowser.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```